# Java and Hibernate, lock objects during update/write but reads always allowed

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, locking, db2

My application uses Java, Hibernate, and IBM DB2 database. I would like to use pessimistic locking when updating and writing data so other threads need to wait for the resource to be available before trying to update it. However, I want threads to always be able to read data (regardless of whether it is locked or not i.e. transactions are open for the data), and read operations never lock data. What isolation level would fulfil this in Hibernate and IBM DB2? Thanks.

Comment: Which category of OS does your DB2 server reside on?

Comment: That is such pessimistic logging that I don't believe any RDBMS does that... At the java level however you can use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` to achieve that.

Comment: WarrenT: In runs on Redhat
fge: Why not? To me it sounds like a very common situation. Pessimistic locking for edits, Read Committed isolation level for reads

Comment: What processes are locking the data in the first place?  Note that some factors may force the optimizer to lock rows _outside_ of what's going to be updated (index/storage page, or the entire table!).  If this is a human-interacting process, be prepared to have it be locked over lunch/vacation.  How are you accessing this?  It may be difficult to retain/rejoin the lock if you're doing web services (where you may not even talk to the same application server!).  What's the plan for statement timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Hibernate, but on the DB2 side you can use either uncommitted read isolation level or cursor stability isolation along with the activated "currently committed" semantics (the latter is available in DB2 LUW 9.7 and later).